# OnTouchListener for ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-viewpager, ontouchlistener, android-viewpager2

I recently changed the ViewPager in my application to a ViewPager2. I had set an onTouchListener to the viewPager object to detect gestures (onFling and onLongPress), as such:

```
mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        mDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent); // use the custom gesture detector to detect onFling and onLongPress touch events.
        return true; 
    }
});
```

The onTouchListener for the viewPager was working fine before the refactor to the ViewPager2. I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60328756/prevent-swiping-of-viewpager2-when-ontouch-of-inner-view) but it didn't work and could not find more info online.

How can we set an `OnTouchListener` to the `ViewPager2`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because ViewPager2 is a ViewGroup, the final target is the recyclerview in it. The setOnTouchListener is not called because the recyclerview intercepts the event and calls the onTouchEvent first.

The right way to add customised onTouch logic is to call

```
mViewPager.getChildAt(0).setOnTouchListener{...}
```

Comment: Where this code has to be put? I tried in several places (when I create the viewpager, on page select, inside the page onCreateView and onViewCreated), different child positions, but never worked.

Comment: wow, that's... a weird way to have to implement this. Hope they'll add an API to the pager itself at some point

Comment: If you add a `GestureDetector` that overrides `onFling` you will get a crash when swiping. `Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.example.Class.onFling, parameter e1`.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to add customised onTouch logic is to call

```
viewPager2.getChildAt(viewPager2.getCurrentItem()).setOnTouchListener(...)
```