# ViewPager2 with Tablayout inside a fragment shows no swipe effect in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, android-viewpager2

In my MainActivity I have a viewpager2 with Tablayout with 5 tabs. The swipe there is working fine. But in one of the 5 tabs I again have a viewpager2 with a tablayout of 3 tabs. In the inner viewpager2 (which is inside a fragment) the swipe isnt working at all and I don't understand why.

The outer viewpager2 is inside a activity while the inner viewpager2 is in the fragment

**Viewpager2 inside fragment , swipe not working :**

```
class FreelancerMyProjectsFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var binding : FragmentFreelancerMyProjectsBinding
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_freelancer_my_projects, container, false)



        setUpViewPager()
        addTabs()

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun addTabs() {

        TabLayoutMediator(binding.projectsTabLayout, binding.projectsViewPager) { tab, position ->
        }.attach()


        binding.projectsTabLayout.getTabAt(0)?.text =resources.getText(R.string.active)
        binding.projectsTabLayout.getTabAt(1)?.text =resources.getText(R.string.bids)
        binding.projectsTabLayout.getTabAt(2)?.text =resources.getText(R.string.past)
    }

    private fun setUpViewPager() {

        val adapter = ScreenSlidePagerAdapterNewForFragment(this)

        adapter.addFragment(ActiveProjectsFragment())

        adapter.addFragment(BidsFragment())

        adapter.addFragment(PastProjectFragment())

        binding.projectsViewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 3

        binding.projectsViewPager.adapter = adapter

    }
}


class ScreenSlidePagerAdapterNewForFragment(fragment: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

        var fragmentList: ArrayList<Fragment> = ArrayList()

        public fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment) {

            fragmentList.add(fragment)

        }


        override fun getItemCount(): Int{ return fragmentList.size}

        override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {return fragmentList[position]}
    }
```

**And here is the layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/projectsViewPager"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/projectsTabLayout"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        </androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>


        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/projectsTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="40dp"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/ProjectTabLayoutFreelancer"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>



    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</layout>
```

Please can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The outer Viewpager is preventing the inner viewpager from receiving touch events. You need to intercept the event and stop the outer viewpager from swiping. See the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60328756/6258197) for implemented solution code

Comment: Okay,I will try this. But why is it that when I used viewpager it was swiping normally, but when i'm using viewpager2 we have this problem?